# Unable to add XMLSlurper to Eclipse Groovy project

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, xmlslurper

I want to use XMLSlurper in my Groovy project in Eclipse.

I found out that i need to use Groovy-All Jar from https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.codehaus.groovy
to get those functionalities.

After adding them to my Eclipse Project, when i use the following code

```
  import groovy.util.XmlSlurper;
class myGroovyClass1 {
    static void main(String[] args) {
    def parser = new XmlSlurper();

     }
}
```

I get the error ***Groovy:Unable to resolve class groovy.util.XmlSlurper***

Here is my Build Path.

[image]

Comment: Groovy 2.5+ does not have an all "fat" jar. You need to add individual jar modules to your classpath or switch to Groovy 2.4 compiler in eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

Instead of adding groovy-all. I added groovy-xml Jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgroovyxml212jar.htm and performed

> `import groovy.xml.*;`